# How do you play a video through JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am working on an IDE based off of JavaScript. I need to figure out how to play videos using only JavaScript. I have looked online and found next to nothing.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
var vid = document.createElement('video');
vid.src = src;
vid.autoPlay = true;
document.body.appendChild(vid);
```

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you edit your question to tell us what that code currently does and what you expect it to do.  That's assuming you want help with that code -- you didn't actually ask a question in your question.

Comment: What was your google search term? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vid.play(); To play a video.
```

Link to tutorial: [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp)

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

function playVid() { 
    vid.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/n8tfqLof/)

### EDIT: Here is how you add controls

**HTML:**

```
<button id="playPause">Pause</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var pp = document.getElementById('playPause');
pp.onclick = function(){
    if(vid.paused){
        vid.play();
        pp.innerHTML = "Pause";
    }else{
        vid.pause();
        pp.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
};
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/n8tfqLof/1/)

### Adding default controls

```
vid.controls = true;
```

Comment: When I do this it makes no difference. Nothing shows up at all.

Comment: @crank123 check the demo

Comment: How do I add the controls?

Comment: I mean the default controls.